# How to build android app fast?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, compilation, gradle

I have an project with 4 android libraries, each time I run the project, it takes almost a minute for eclipse to run a build on my phone, this too much time consuming.

- Is there any better way to make it faster?
- If I switch it to a gradle project will it be a little bit faster?

Comment: Even my very simple projects take that long to compile, regardless of if it is in eclipse or in android studio (which makes gradle projects). I've heard that a solid state hard driver compiles faster in most cases, but other than that I don't think you can make it any better.

Comment: I'm using mac pro(which has ssd) for development, but it is still the case.

Comment: Close Unwanted projects in your Eclipse IDE, Use Classic theme by selecting Windows->preference->general tab->appearance->classic, Disable Lint Error Checking from Android Tab->Lint Error Checking-> uncheck two check boxes in right side... This all will speed up your build..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the libraries gets compiles when you are making changes on your main project. In my experience copying and installing the app to the device takes the most time. Especially if you are working on an SSD. You can influence this by reducing the size of your apk. Maybe you can remove some resources while under development.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to make it faster?

You should look at your files and local output, first answer by @user714965 is great.

> - If I switch it to a gradle project will it be a little bit faster?

Try it within Eclipse `http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/` and compare yourself.